# django form commit=false after how to save many to many field data

Tags: django, django-forms

**Model.py**

```
class Branch(models.Model): # Branch Master
    status_type = (
        ("a",'Active'),
        ("d",'Deactive'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = 'a')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Vendor(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ("a",'Active'),
        ("d",'Deactive'),
    )
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique = True)
    email  =  models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique = True)
    gst = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique = True)
    pan_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique = True)
    add_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    add_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    add_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank = True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = 'a')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
```

**form.py**
**i want save like created_by field**

class VendorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model  = Vendor
fields = '**all**'
exclude = ['created_by', 'branch']
widgets = {
'company':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'phone':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'gst':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'pan_no':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'add_1':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'add_2':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'add_3':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
'Remark':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'2'}),
'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
}

**Views.py**
**I have pass branch in session.**
**I want to save with branch which is many to many field**

```
    def Add_Vendor(request): # for vendor add
        msg = ""
        msg_type = ""
        branch_id = request.session['branch_id']
        branch_data = Branch.objects.get(id = branch_id)
        form = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                form = VendorForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid:
                    vendor_add = form.save(commit=False)
                    vendor_add.created_by = request.user
                    vendor_add.instance.branch = branch_data.id
                    vendor_add.save()
                    form.save_m2m() # for m to m field save                
                    msg_type = "success"
                    msg = "Vendor Added."
                    form = VendorForm(initial={'branch':branch_id})
            except:
                msg_type = "error"
                msg = str(form.errors)
                print(msg)
        else:
            form = VendorForm(initial={'branch':branch_id})
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'branch_data':branch_data,
            'msg_type':msg_type,
            'msg':msg,
            'btn_type':'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
            'form_title':'Vendor Form',
            'tree_main_title':'Vendor',
            'v_url':'vendor_page',
            'tree_title':'Add Form',
        }
        return render(request, 'base/vendor_master/form_vendor.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *not* to work with `commit=False` in the first place:

```
def Add_Vendor(request):  # for vendor add
    branch_id = request.session['branch_id']
    branch_data = get_object_or_404(Branch, pk=branch_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VendorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.created_by = request.user
            form.instance.branch = branch_data.id
            vendor_add = form.save()
            vendor_add.branch.add(branch_data)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = VendorForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'branch_data': branch_data,
        'btn_type': 'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
        'form_title': 'Vendor Form',
        'tree_main_title': 'Vendor',
        'v_url': 'vendor_page',
        'tree_title': 'Add Form',
    }
    return render(request, 'base/vendor_master/form_vendor.html', context)
```

You can simplify your form by automatically adding `form-control` to each widget:

```
class VendorForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            attrs = field.widget.attrs
            attrs['class'] = attrs.get('class', '') + ' form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        exclude = ['created_by', 'branch']
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can set a field [**`editable=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#editable). Then the field does not show up in the `ModelForm`s and `ModelAdmin`s by default. In this case for example with `created_by`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* pass messages manually to the template. Django has the [*messages framework* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/), which allows to add messages to the request, which will then be delivered the next time a template renders these messages. This makes delivering *multiple* messages convenient, as well as setting different log levels to the messages.